# Are there any hidden fees for using PayPal?

Tags: paypal

After years of inability to use PayPal due to hard restrictions and regulations of my country, I eventually found a way to use PayPal. I'm going to:

1. Send/received money to/from my internet friends all over the world.
2. Withdraw money from ATM machines in Egypt.
3. Do some freelance work (using fiverr and similar websites).
4. Maybe receive donations for volunteering activities.

My question is: If I have no balance in my PayPal account, will PayPal deduct any fees from my credit card for any reason? I mean are there monthly or annual fees for using PayPal? Are there fine/fees for not being active on PayPal? I mean what if didn't make any transactions for a long period of time? Are there any cases where PayPal deduct from my credit card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think PayPal is pretty transparent on their fee schedule.

https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-fees